# SELECT not working properly in Angular2/4 and SAFARI

Tags: angular, safari

I'm having big problems on SAFARI with basic html SELECT component.

This is the code:

### top declaration

```
idFamily:any = null;
listProductFamily: ProductFamily[];
```

### listProductFamily loading

```
    this.productFamilyService.GetAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.listProductFamily = data;
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      }
    );
```

### html component

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="idFamily" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <option *ngFor="let f of listProductFamily" [value]="f.idFamily">{{f.code}} - {{f.family}}</option>
</select>
```

The problem is this:

On **SAFARI** when the select is loaded, it is set on the first value of the option list.

On **Chrome, IE, FF** the select is set on NULL value (empty)

On Safari, even if the select is set on a value actually the idFamily variable where it is binded has not value... idFamily gets a value only if the user select a value... thats it.

I don't know how to solve this problem...

Hope its clear
Thanks to support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this same issue where Safari will select the first item in a `<select>` when the ngModel property doesn't match because it is in an 'empty' state and there's no matching item in the array. My workaround was to add a matching empty `<option>`. In your case, I think this will work:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="idFamily">
    <option [value]="null"></option>
    <option *ngFor="let f of listProductFamily" [value]="f.idFamily">{{f.code}} - {{f.family}}</option>
</select>
```

In our case, we use uuids for model ids, so we use empty string for initial values. Component:

```
export class SomeComponent {
   id = '';
}
```

template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="id">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

In either case, Safari should select the empty option on initial load.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Standalone

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="idFamily">
    <option *ngFor="let f of listProductFamily" [ngValue]="f.idFamily">{{f.code}} - {{f.family}}</option>
</select>
```

> standalone: Defaults to false. If this is set to true, the ngModel
>   will not register itself with its parent form, and will act as if it's
>   not in the form. This can be handy if you have form meta-controls,
>   a.k.a. form elements nested in the  tag that control the display
>   of the form, but don't contain form data.

Check AngularDoc For MoreInfo:https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options

Comment: I have removed the standalone as you suggested but the problem persists...

Comment: its too complex to add, I integrate the question posting ts code

Comment: No, the problem is that SAFARI load the component and set the value on the first option... The problem in on browser management, the code its ok

Comment: you are setting the idFamily to null

Comment: yes, and its ok... But SAFARI shows set always the first option as selected... Firefox and other browser shows and empy option...

Comment: use [ngValue] instead of value and check

Comment: I did it but nothing changed... Safari has a different behavior

Comment: are you trying add empty value for default?

Comment: Yes I did it but nothing happens... Seems a common problem on SAFARI...

Comment: if you set the value idFamily is it working properly on other browser?

Comment: Yes on other browser no problem

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved a similar issue by using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Doing the following will set child form values to `null`, effectively clearing the defaults that Safari has set:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.exampleFormName.reset();
}
```

Note: `this.exampleFormName` is of type `FormGroup`

I am also using `*ngFor` to load option values dynamically and `reset()` doesn't interfere with it!

Comment: How do you initialize `this.exampleFormName`?